# My Html text distorted on web

Tags: html

Hey guys I know it's bit weird situation, but if anybody face and resolved this problem before, would be able to help me. For example I have written `<p>sydney's</p>`in my html markup and It looks something like this on webpage - `Sydneyâ€™s`.

Platform I am using is Asp.net 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whoever voted this down, give me the reason please.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I am not demanding, I am requesting that if I have asked something silly then please tell me.

Comment: -1 for unneccesary suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have the wrong encoding format in your webpage `(ISO-8859-1)`, you could change it or more simply, you could just use the HTML entity `&#39;` in place of the apostrophe. Therefore it would be `<p>sydney&#39;s</p>`.